# Why does Ubuntu 12.04 detect only one USB Ethernet adapter?

Tags: networking, ubuntu-12.04, network-adapter

The problem is that I am connecting three client computers to another central computer through:

1. the one normal Ethernet port connected to one client computer (eth0)
2. two USB to Ethernet adapters connected to the remaining two client computers as eth1

The problem is when the SECOND usb to Ethernet adapter is connected, it is not shown as eth2 in the `ifconfig` output. When I remove the first one, this second one appears as eth1.

I don't know whether the problem occurs because both adapters took the same logical name (eth1) or if Ubuntu 12.04 doesn't support connecting 2 usb to Ethernet adapters at the same time.

Why can I only use one of my USB Ethernet adapters?

Comment: Are they both the exact same make/model? Plug in one of them and run `lsusb -nnvv` and see what the USB ID is of one of them. Maybe the specific driver used by this chipset is not capable of supporting multiple instances. This could also be something that has been fixed in a newer kernel version than the version in Ubuntu 12.04.